# div slider based on document width

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that slides out when clicked upon (#close-bar). This is working fine, but I want it to only be visible with the other functions that get fired when doc width is 480px but be hidden on doc width above 480px.

This is the [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/lupis/gv6ffj0a/1/) on jsfiddle.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(ChangeDiv);
    $(window).trigger("resize");   
});

function ChangeDiv() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 480) {
        $("#menu").after($("#header"));
        $("#headerRight form").prependTo($("#footer"));
    } else {
        $("#header").after($("#menu"));
        $("#footer form").appendTo($("#headerRight"));
    }
}

var speed = 300;
        $('#close-bar').on('click', function(){

            var $$ = $(this),
                panelWidth = $('#hiddenPanel').outerWidth();

            if( $$.is('.myButton') ){
                $('#hiddenPanel').animate({right:0}, speed);
                $$.removeClass('myButton')
            } else {
                $('#hiddenPanel').animate({right:-panelWidth}, speed);
                $$.addClass('myButton')
            }

        });
```

Thanks
-Sohail

Comment: So do you want to hide `#close-bar` and forbid sliding out for `#close-bar` when window's width is less than _480px_ and allow sliding out for `#close-bar` when window's width equals or is greater than _480px_?

Comment: Do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/gv6ffj0a/2/ ?

Comment: thanks, I see your suggestion by adding a media query to it, but I think you may have misunderstood me,  your solution negates the effect of the rest of the divs to be manipulated with my script.
The reply from @Giorgio is the one that works out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's sufficient to hide it via CSS above 480px ([**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gv6ffj0a/3/)), right?

```
@media only screen and (min-width:480px) 
{
    #close-bar {
        display:none;
    }
}
```